# Fonts in LaTeX--Charter

Tags: fonts

I'm using droidsans in conjunction with charter but for some reason I cannot seem to get droid sans to work. How might I get this font to work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}
\author{test}
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The Introduction

\end{document}
```

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.28)  7 DEC 2019 21:14 entering
>   extended mode  \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
>   **main.tex (/compile/main.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01> (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File:
>   size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
>   \c@part=\count80 \c@section=\count81 \c@subsection=\count82
>   \c@subsubsection=\count83 \c@paragraph=\count84
>   \c@subparagraph=\count85 \c@figure=\count86 \c@table=\count87
>   \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   \bibindent=\dimen102 )
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/droidsans.sty
>   Package: droidsans 2011/09/11 Droid Sans
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
>   Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
>   \KV@toks@=\toks14 )
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/slantsc/slantsc.sty
>   Package: slantsc 2012/01/01 v2.11 Provide Slanted an Italic Small Caps
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty Package:
>   ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC) ) LaTeX
>   Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 35. LaTeX Info: Redefining
>   \slshape on input line 45. LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input
>   line 55. LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 65. ))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
>   Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
>   \inpenc@prehook=\toks15 \inpenc@posthook=\toks16 )
>   (/compile/output.aux) \openout1 = `output.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line> 9. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:
>   ... okay on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
>   OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
>   line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on
>   input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9. LaTeX Font
>   Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9. LaTeX
>   Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking
>   defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay
>   on input line 9. LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for
>   size (Font)              <12> on input line 11. LaTeX Font Info:
>
>   External font`cmex10' loaded for size (Font)              <8> on
>   input line 11. LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for
>   size (Font)              <6> on input line 11. [1
>
> {/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (/compi le/output.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 
>   352 strings out of 492616  4652 string characters out of 6128979 
>   62186 words of memory out of 5000000  4319 multiletter control
>   sequences out of 15000+600000  7280 words of font info for 26 fonts,
>   out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
>   26i,6n,19p,170b,187s stack positions out of
>   5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>    Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 37857 bytes).
>   PDF statistics:  24 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  16
>   compressed objects within 1 object stream  0 named destinations out of
>   1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of
>   10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: what error or warning do you get when you load the font. Are you using luatex?, xetex? pdftex? ...

Comment: I'm flattered that you think we can read minds `:-)` but we need a little more than that...

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't get an error as such, it's more what is the function of droid sans? When I disable charter it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: It is impossible to guess what you did or what could be wrong. LaTeX will not give you the wrong font with no warning. Please make a small document that sets (or tries to set) a line in droid sans and show the log file that you get.

Comment: There, I attached my log and MWE :)

Comment: You also probably want to load either `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `droidsans` style makes the `\droidsans` command available, which can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\begin{document}
{\droidsans This uses Droid Sans}
\end{document}
```

If you specify the `defaultsans` option, Droid Sans will be the default sans-serif font used by `\textsf{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\begin{document}
\textsf{This uses Droid Sans}
\end{document}
```

If you specify the `default` option, Droid Sans will be used as the default font for the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{droidsans}
\begin{document}
This uses Droid Sans
\end{document}
```

In your case the last version is probably what you are looking for.